# VBA InStr With ~

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to extract a date from a cell that is not in standard date format.

The Cell in Question has the string "10/9～10/13" in it.

I know this because I initially find the suspect cell by using a Range.Find function. (I tried .Value, .Value2, and .Text here to no avail).

```
        text = .UsedRange.Find("~~").Value
```

If I use debug.Print text then

```
debug.Print text
10/9_10/13
```

Interestingly enough the ~ disappears. However, debug.Print also reveals this strange behavior.

```
d = InStr(1, "10/9_10/13", "_", vbTextCompare)
5
d = InStr(1, text, "_", vbTextCompare)
0
```

I thought perhaps text isn't a string?

```
debug.Print TypeName(text)
String
```

If you could explain why VBA is exhibiting this apparently inconsistent behavior that would be very useful.

Comment: I thought InStr was literal in any case...? You shouldn't have to do anything. Try `InStr(1, dCell.Text, "_", vbTextCompare)`.

Comment: What does `debug.print ascw(mid(dcell, 5, 1))` output?

Comment: I changed dCell to a different name since it isn't a cell. @Rory debug.print ascw(mid(dcell, 5, 1)) outputs -162

Comment: @Jeeped, dCell.Text doesn't do anything since dCell is a string not a range.

Comment: *Interestingly enough the ~ disappears* - That is weird as this should not happen. In my test the date still is 10/9~10/13. May be you are doing something else in between or your text variable contains something else

Comment: @user3750428 FYI backticks are for formatting *inline code* - by surrounding a @ user ping with them, you're making the system treat it like code, not a ping.

Comment: I'm on a Mac, maybe that's making a difference.

Comment: @PankajJaju Thank you for testing. I went back to look and the cell had the following: 10/9～10/13. Apparently the tilde is not a normal ~.  So apparently Excel treats this case poorly as it has no idea what character ～ is.

Comment: 162 or 126? I suspect being on a Mac is the cause.

Comment: @Rory it output -162

Comment: On a PC 162 should be `¢` and not anything like a tilde, so my guess is you're right and it's a Unicode/Mac problem.

Comment: @Rory `-162` not `162`. I don't know how you can have a negative in there but it works.

Comment: Assuming you cut/paste to get the cell contents into your question, that character is a **Full Width Tilde**.  The Unicode for that character is `65374` or, Hex `FF5E`. Of interest with regard to @Brad observation is that `65374` = `65536-162`

Comment: @Brad note that the character in question is Unicode `65374`.  In Hex that would be `FF5E`.  `-162` represented in signed 16-bit 2's complement would also be `FF5E`

Comment: @user3750428 - The VBA IDE is not unicode complaint. So do not worry about debug.print ... if you want to check, print the value in a cell. If you want to do instr, use the method that I've shown in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have seen AscW returns -162, you can use that value to find the unicode char in vba

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I put your data in **D1** and then I ran:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim dCell As String, txet As String
    dCell = Range("D1").Value
    Debug.Print dCell

    txet = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Find("~~").Value
    Debug.Print txet
End Sub
```

*(I used txet rather than text to avoid any confusion with the Property of the same name)* and got:

[image]

Is it possible that what you have is not *tilda* but some other unicode character that looks like *tilda*?

Comment: Yeah, thanks to @PankajJaju I looked for that. ～ is apparently not pastable into vba. It's probably some unicode character.